# Class 'Validate' not found in Laravel Validation process

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I am studying Laravel now and I have a problem with display validation messages in my page. 
Here's the error I have after clicking the submit button

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Class 'Validate' not found
----------------------------------------------
Open: C:\wamp\vhosts\flax_order\app\routes.php
                    'lastname'      =>  'min:2|max:15',
                    'firstname'     =>  'min:2|max:20',
                    'middlename'    =>  'min:10|max:20',
                    'password'      =>  'required|min:8|max:30',
                    'cpassword'     =>  'required|same:password'
                );

                $validator = Validate::make(Input::all(), $rules);

                if($validator->fails()) {
```

I put the validation process in my route.
Here's my sample code.

Here's the form

```
@if ($error->has())

                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                @endforeach

            @endif

<form action="{{ action('EmployeesController@handleRegister') }}" method="POST" role="form">

                <p class="required">Fields marked with (*) are required.</p>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Employee Code: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control tooltip_detail" name="emp_code" data-toggle="tooltip" value="" data-placement="top" title="{{ $instructions['code'] }}" />
                </div>
.....
```

Here's my controller

```
public function register() 
    {

        $instructions = array(
                            'code'          => 'Ex: 0001',
                            'lastname'      => 'Ex: Peterson',
                            'firstname'     => 'Ex: Johlo',
                            'middlename'    => 'Ex: P.',
                            'password'      => 'Choose your password carefully',
                            'cpassword'     => 'Repeat your password'
                        );

        return View::make('register', array(
            'page_title'    => 'Flax: Food Ordering',
            'instructions'  => $instructions,
        ));

    }

    public function handleRegister() 
    {

    }
```

Here's my routes.php

```
Route::get('/','EmployeesController@index');
Route::get('/register', 'EmployeesController@register');
Route::get('/handleRegister', 'EmployeesController@handleRegister');

Route::post('/handleRegister', function() 
            {

                $rules = array(
                    'emp_code'      =>  'numeric|exists:employees',
                    'lastname'      =>  'min:2|max:15',
                    'firstname'     =>  'min:2|max:20',
                    'middlename'    =>  'min:10|max:20',
                    'password'      =>  'required|min:8|max:30',
                    'cpassword'     =>  'required|same:password'
                );

                $validator = Validate::make(Input::all(), $rules);

                if($validator->fails()) {

                    $messages = $validator->messages();

                    return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);

                } else {

                    fd('ok');

                }

            }
        );
```

I don't know where did I go wrong. Can you help me with this? I am not so good in Laravel.

Comment: Thanks. It solved. Sorry for the simple question. :)

Comment: I have a question. In validating is it necessary that I should do this in the route? Or can I do this in my controller also and model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the `laravel` class which is `validator` not `validate`

Thats what the error message is saying. That class does not exit. In short it giving you hint

Comment: Ok thanks for the help sir. I have a problem after I clicked the submit button I have this error:

`ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Undefined variable: error (View: C:\wamp\vhosts\flax_order\app\views\register.blade.php)`

I already passed the error with the use of this line but it doesn't display in my template

` return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);`

Comment: Ok thanks, the tutorial I read about validation is not so correct there are some typo error. That's why I got these error. Thanks for reminding me.. :)

Comment: Just like an ebook?  If yes, I don't have yet. i am just relying in the tutorials in the main web and some blogs.. :)

Comment: Ok but it's not complete yet.. it's 449 pages

Comment: @Jerielle i dont know but i like that book. so best of luck any way

Comment: Ok I found one here's the link :) 
http://www35.zippyshare.com/v/76470301/file.html